# Develop loop in ARM assembly

Tags: assembly, while-loop, arm, keil

I have to write a program that initializes register X, Y, and Z to zero then loops 10 times, each time adding 1 to register X. If register X is even, add one to register Y and if register X is divisible by 3, add one to register Z.

I wrote some code but I'm unsure if it is right and I'd appreciate any feedback.

```
       R0, #0
       R1, #0
       R2, #0
 Loop: R3, #0
       CMP R0, #10
       BEQ endif
       ADD R0, #1
       TST R0, #1
       ADDEQ R1, #1
       MOV R3, R0 MOD 3
       CMP R3, #0
       ADDEQ R2, #1
       B loop
 Endif:
```

Comment: You could perhaps go a little heavier on the comments?

Comment: Code review questions really belong on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/.  If you're not sure if it's right or not, then you should test it to see if it works.  If it works in your testing, then post it on codereview.  If it doesn't, then debug it (by single-stepping with a debugger).  If you get stuck, post here on SO with a specific question and the details of what you see when debugging.

Answer (score 1):

[code review questions aren't really on topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46438537/develop-loop-in-arm-assembly#comment79834747_46438537), but we sometimes make exceptions for asm.

> I'd appreciate any feedback.

Asm loops should normally look like C `do { } while( condition )`.

It's usually best to put the conditional branch at the bottom of a loop, so you don't need a separate unconditional branch.  (Especially when a loop is known to run at least once, so you don't need a check before the first iteration or a jump to conditional.)

In your case, that would be

```
                    @ do{
    ...
add r0, #1
cmp r0, #10
bne Loop            @ } while(r0 != 10)
```

Or start with r0 = 10, and use `subs r0, #1` to subtract and set flags, so you don't need a separate `cmp` instruction.

---

```
   TST R0, #1
   ADDEQ R1, #1
```

works fine.  You could also have unconditionally added the low bit, instead of conditionally adding 0 or 1.

```
   AND   R3, R0, #1
   ADD   R1, R3
```

If you were in Thumb2 mode, this would require an extra MOV instruction to extract the low bit non-destructively, because you wouldn't have 3-operand `AND`.  Or would it?  You could use bit-shifts to wipe out all the other bits, and IIRC Thumb2 still allows shifts as part of register operands.

```
   MOV   R3, R0 LSL #31    @  I think this is legal syntax
   ADD   R1, R3 LSR #31
```

---

```
MOV R3, R0 MOD 3
```

This looks really dodgy.  Does that even assemble?  Pretty sure ARM can only shift and rotate.  Mod 3 is a very expensive calculation.

What you should do instead is use a down-counter that counts down from 3 and resets to 3 when it hits zero.  You can do that and the conditional add using ARM conditional / predicated execution.

```
SUBS  R3, #1
MOVEQ R3, #3
ADDEQ R2, #1
```